# AutoMapper nulls out properties in destination object when the destination is an existing object with some populated properties

Tags: c#, automapper

EDIT: please never mind. It functions fine as I have stated below. I had a huge mistake in my original code as it is quite a bit more complex than my example. Thank you.

```
public class Full {
  public string A {get;set;}
  public string B {get;set;}
}

public class Half1 {
 public string A {get;set;}
}

public class Half2{
 public string B {get;set;}
}

CreateMap<Half1, Full>();
CreateMap<Half2, Full>();

var half1Items = //some data with A populated
var half2Items = //some data with B populated

//this will populate fullItems with A properties - so far so good
var fullItems = Mapper.Map<List<Half1>, List<Full>(half1Items);

//this will make all A properties null and populate all B properties - very sad :'(
fullItems = Mapper.Map(half2Items, fullItems);
```

Comment: `.ForMember(x => x.sdfsdf, opt => opt.Ignore())` ?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to explicitly ignore the property.

```
.ForMember(x => x.sdfsdf, opt => opt.Ignore())
```

Why do you want to do this? Because ideally you should be validating your mapping with `AssertConfigurationIsValid`, as annoying as this is, it will save a whole bunch of releases from breaking weirdly and unexpectedly.

> AutoMapper checks to make sure that every single Destination type
> member has a corresponding type member on the source type.

Or if you are feeling lucky and like living on the edge of your seat

```
.ForAllOtherMembers(opt => opt.Ignore());
```

Comment: `ForAllOtherMembers` is on its way out :)